# Variadic template template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

The following code does not compiles using clang 3.0, is this because I have done it wrongly? Because it is not allowed in c++11 or because it is not supported in clang?

```
template<int OFFSET>
struct A {
    enum O { offset = OFFSET };
};

template < template <int T> class Head, typename... Tail>
struct C : public Head<1>, private C<Tail> { };

int main()
{
    C< A, A > c1;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
test3.cxx:99:42: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
    struct C : public Head<1>, private C<Tail> { };
                                         ^
test3.cxx:103:15: error: use of class template A requires template arguments
        C< A, A > c1;
              ^
test3.cxx:94:12: note: template is declared here
    struct A {
           ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: `Tail` is a template parameter pack, but you never expand the pack when instantiating `C<>` -- what type do you expect `C<>` to be instantiated with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three issues:

`Tail` is to be a variadic list of templates, not of types. Hence it should be

```
template<int> class... Tail
```

instead of

```
typename... Tail
```

and you need to explicitly expand the parameter pack with `private C<Tail...>` instead of `private C<Tail>`.

And you'll need to implement the base case, for when `Tail...` is empty:

```
// base case
template < template <int> class Head>
struct C<Head> : public Head<1> { };
```

(This is compiling for with Clang 3.0)

The entire piece of code now:

```
template<int OFFSET>
struct A {
    enum O { offset = OFFSET };
};

template < template <int> class Head, template<int> class... Tail>
struct C : public Head<1>, private C<Tail...> { };
template < template <int> class Head>
struct C<Head> : public Head<1> { };

int main()
{
    C< A, A > c1;
    return 0;
}
```